# How to get 1st true value for *ngIf inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of items that need to be displayed based on roles. I need the first value which will fulfil the ngIf condition.

I am adding my code below:

My Array(kind of how it will originally look):

```
parentTabList = [ 
        {
            name: 'abc',
            label: 'abc',
            icon : 'question_answer',
            role : ['vend_perm','vend_temp','vend_subs']
        },
        {
            name: 'xyz',
            label: 'xyz',
            icon : 'question_answer',
            role : ['vend_perm','vend_subs']
        }
    ]
```

My Html: -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let form of parentTabList let i = index">
    <li *ngIf="form.role.includes(userRole)">
        <a (click)="methodName(form)">
            {{form.label}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

UserRole is a string value that I get when a user logs-in.

I need to add a ngClass to the anchor tag if it is the first anchor to be displayed.
(I am a noob at StackOverflow, please let me know if any more explanation is required).

Comment: did you tried with hardcoded value ?

Comment: **I need to add a ngClass to anchor tag if it is the first anchor to be displayed.** what this mean? show us the expected output

Comment: `<a [ngClass]="{form.role.includes(userRole) == yourConditionToCheck ? 'yourClass' : 'notYourClass' }"'`

Comment: How about a plain CSS solution? `li:first-child > a { background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify first element of the array with index.

But as per my understanding you need filter this array with roles and then apply ***ngClass*** to first element from filtered list.

So add method to return filtered array with respect to roles

**In Template:**

```
 filterParentTabList(parentList: any) {
     return parentList.filter(form => form.role.includes(this.userRole));
 }
```

**In View:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let form of filterParentTabList(parentTabList); let i = index">
    <li>
        <a [ngClass]="{ 'addYourClaaName': i === 0 }" (click)="methodName(form)">
            {{form.label}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this. In this code, f represents the first position of your array.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let form of parentTabList; let i = index; let f = first">
    <li *ngIf="f">
        <a (click)="methodName(f)">
            `{{f.label}}`
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

> If you want other position of your array, you can write like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a getter that will get you the index. This can then be used in the html

```typescript
  get firstIndex() {
    return this.parentTabList.indexOf(this.parentTabList.find(({role}) => 
      role.includes(this.userRole)))
  }
```

Now in your html

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let form of parentTabList let i = index">
    <li *ngIf="form.role.includes(userRole)">
        <a [ngClass]="{redText: firstIndex === i}" (click)="methodName(form)">
            {{form.label}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

[See Stackblitz Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kpauzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This might not work if first element not satisfied `<li>` ngIf condition.. ;)

Comment: @ganesh045  have you checked the demo Link? This works exactly as per OP question requirement

Comment: Yeah, you added `userRole` as static value `vend_temp` what if OP assigning it dynamically

Comment: Also you are checking condition twice, with ngIf of  `<li>` and with getter method which is not recommended where you can easily avoid in this situation.

Comment: @ganesh045 that's why I added a select  to dynamically change the value of userRole, If you had check the demo this is all demostrated clearly